# spark dataframe read text file without headers

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

i have a text file with no headers, how can i read it using spark dataframe api and specify headers. Is there a way to specify my schema

sample_data = spark.read.option("header", "false").text(sample)

print "Data size is {}".format(sample_data.count())

print type(sample_data)

print sample_data.take(2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, save your file as csv. You can specify the schema:

```
schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("column1", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("column2", DoubleType(), True), \
    StructField("column3", IntegerType(), True)])
```

And so on.
If you're using spark 2.0 +:

```
spark.read.csv(
    "file.csv", header=True, schema=schema
)
```

If you're using spark < 2.0:

```
sales = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv')\
    .options(header='true', delimiter='whatever youre using as delimiter')\
    .load('file.csv', schema = schema)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to do in python as well , the schema part of it .

Comment: my bad..this is python.

Answer (score 0):

```
df=spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferschema", "true").option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED").load(<path_name>)
# header can made to false, if there is no schema
```